# Automatic script - Arithmetic Operations on 12 columns lag

Tags: python, pandas

I got a table where YYYY MM columns got crime figures. i.e. number of violent crimes per Ward.
I am doing manual tasks of calculating diffrence for each month between 2019 and 2020. I am using Pandas.

```
df['03 vs 03']= df["201903"] / df["202003"]
df['04 vs 04']= df["201904"] / df["202004"]
df['05 vs 05']= df["201905"] / df["202005"]
```

Can you advise on how to make it variable based so that I will not need to write 12 lines of this code for each month ? So if I get 10 years of data I would need to do it 10 x 12 times. I bet there is a better way.

I would think month should be varible X and year variable Y. Just syntax wise I just have no idea how to progress. Happy to follow on hints rather than whole solution.

Regards
D.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give it a try and include the code you write /sample data / and full error messages about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help. See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks I will do that with any new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the variable for year and moneth and want to increase by month, you can do something like this:

```
y=2019
m=1
while True:
    current = f'{y}{str(m).zfill(2)}'
    next = f'{y + 1}{str(m).zfill(2)}'
    print(current, ' ', next)
    m += 1
    if m > 12:
        m = 1
        y += 1
    if y > 2020:
        break
```

Output:

```
201901   202001
201902   202002
201903   202003
201904   202004
201905   202005
201906   202006
201907   202007
201908   202008
201909   202009
201910   202010
201911   202011
201912   202012
202001   202101
```

Comment: Your solution gives text output. In my code each line was dividing two columns and geting result to data frame. I guess what I need is merge of those two ideas somehow :)

Comment: you can perform what you want to do inside this loop, you can use the two variables: current and next to reference the duration